# The Jocaxian’s Train #2

Tags: special-relativity

### What do you think about my mental experiment:

Abstract:

```
     We will show, through a thought experiment, that the special theory of relativity is contradictory and   therefore cannot be true.
```

Introduction
Consider two observers: ObsX and ObsY observing the same event, which is the movement of a particle that goes from point A to point B at a constant velocity. According to the figure:

------------ Start --------------------------

```
                                    [B  ]
                                    [   ]
```

[[  ObsY ]] v ->                        [   ]
[  ^]
[[ ObsX ]]                              [A *]
--------------- Finish -------------------------

```
                           [B *]
                            [  *] 
  [[  ObsY ]] v->            [  *]      
                              [  *]
```

[[ ObsX ]]                         [A *]

---

Two observers (ObsX and ObsY) see the same event:
A particle moving at a constant velocity from point A to point B.

Observer ObsX is in a reference frame at rest relative to points A and B.
Observer ObsY is on a train moving with a constant velocity V horizontally relative to ObsX.

Discussion

From ObsX, the particle moves vertically, with constant velocity Vx, over a distance Dx from point A to point B.

The particle's velocity measured by ObsX will be:

```
              Vx =  Dx/Tx     [ 1 ]
```

Where Tx is the time measured by ObsX from the particle leaving point A until it reaches point B.
On the other hand, observer ObsY is on a train moving with a constant velocity V horizontally relative to ObsX.
ObsY sees the particle moving, not vertically, but diagonally, from point A to point B.
Therefore, the distance (Dy) covered by the particle in the reference frame of ObsY will be greater than Dx. Thus:

```
      Dy > Dx
```

Or also:
Dy = K*Dx      [ 2 ]
Where K > 1
Dx is the distance covered by the particle as measured by ObsX
Dy is the distance covered as measured by ObsY.

However, due to special relativity, the time interval of this event measured by ObsY is slower than that measured by ObsX. This is because ObsY is moving at a relative velocity V with respect to ObsX.

Thus, the time interval of this event, according to special relativity, measured by ObsY will be:

```
                 Ty = Tx / Gamma   [ 3 ]
enter preformatted text here
```

Where gamma is the Lorentz factor:

Gamma = 1/SquareRoot( 1 - V^2 / C^2 )
Therefore: Gamma > 1

Now we can calculate the particle's velocity (Vy) measured by ObsY:

```
                   Vy = Dy / Ty   , but using [2] and [3], we have
                   Vy =  Gamma *  K * Dy  / Tx        [ 4 ]
```

using [1], we have:

```
                   Vy = (Gamma*K)*Vx            [ 5 ]
```

Since Gamma > 1 and K > 1, we can finally conclude that:
Vy > Vx   [ 6 ]
In other words, the velocity measured by ObsY, in motion, is greater than the velocity measured by ObsX.
The problem that arises is: What if the particle is a PHOTON, a particle of light?

Conclusion

We would then have a contradiction in special relativity because, in theory, all observers should measure the same speed of light;

If a particle is a photon then Vx should be equal to Vy.

---

References:
Jocaxian's Train #1
https://www.hilarispublisher.com/open-access/jocaxians-train-2476-2296-1000154.pdf

Comment: Just a few things to note in passing: The DOI in the cited paper leads to a dead link. The publisher, Hilaris, appears on [Beall's List](https://beallslist.net/).

Comment: I have voted to close the question because it is so poorly formatted that I can't make any sense of it.

Comment: I think your error is in the evaluation of $T_y$. Remembering the dictum "moving clocks run slow", I would expect $T_y > T_x$ as the speed of the clock is higher in Y's frame. This problem can be analyzed using Lorentz transforms, and working properly with space-time coordinates. An exact solution within SR should not be too difficult

Comment: I think the time slower in a movement referential ( ObsY ) See the Wiki: 
"...the observer will measure the moving clock as ticking slower than a clock that is at rest in the observer's own reference frame...."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation

Comment: @MarcoOcram The predatory journal isn't any better.

Answer (score 4):

I can't understand your question because it is so poorly formatted. However, I have read the linked paper which describes the 'Jocaxian train' thought experiment, and its conclusions are simply incorrect. Time dilation is indeed reciprocal. If a light is flashed vertically upwards in the frame of a moving train, the light will follow a diagonal path in the frame of the railway track. If the light is flashed vertically upwards in the frame of the track, then it will follow a diagonal path in the frame of the moving train. There is no paradox whatsoever.

Comment: Marco,  I think it is impossible the time dilatate according where the flash ligth is fired.  Or the clock is slower in a referetioal or in another. Not both.

Comment: You misunderstand time dilation. It does not mean that one clock is slower than the other.

Comment: When the clock is in movement it works slower than the other at rest.:

["...Special relativity indicates that, for an observer in an inertial frame of reference, a clock that is moving relative to them will be measured to tick *slower* than a clock that is at rest in their frame of reference. This case is sometimes called special relativistic time dilation...."]

Comment: Time dilation means that the time period between two events that occur in the same place in one inertial frame is always less than the time interval between the same two events in any inertial frame in which they occur in different places. For example, the time period might be 4 seconds in one frame and 8 seconds in the other...

Comment: ...it is the duration of the interval that changes, not the rate at which clocks tick, which is a subtle but important distinction. If you are in a frame in which the interval is 4 seconds, your watch will accurately measure it as 4 seconds. If I am in the other frame in which the interval is 8 seconds, my clocks will measure  it as 8 seconds. Your watch and my clock tick at the same rate, but they are measuring intervals of different lengths.

Comment: To go back to your experiment.... if you bounce light vertically up and down on the moving train, the light returns to the place where it started, so the emission and return of the light are two events occurring at the same place in the frame of the train. However, they occur in two different places in the frame of the track, so the elapsed time between them will be greater in the track frame than in the train frame...

Comment: Conversely, if you bounce light vertically in the frame of the track, it will return to the place it left on the track, so the emission and return of the light are now two events occurring in the same place on the track, but occurring in two different places in the frame of the train. Therefore the interval will now be greater in the train frame than in the track frame.

Comment: Off course time dilatation implies clock is slower than the other, if was the same it would get the same time.

Comment: *****WIKIPEDIA***** : 
["...After compensating for varying signal delays due to the changing distance between an observer and a moving clock (i.e. Doppler effect), the observer will measure the moving clock as ticking ***SLOWER*** than a clock that is at REST in the observer's own reference frame. 
In addition, a clock that is close to a massive body (and which therefore is at lower gravitational potential) will record less elapsed time than a clock situated farther from the said massive body (and which is at a higher gravitational potential)...."]

Comment: @JoaoCarlosHollandBarcellos yes they will 'measure' it as ticking slower because they are comparing it with two clocks that are out of sync in its frame.

Comment: @JoaoCarlosHollandBarcellos the more general point is that SR has a rock solid foundation, so if you think you have found something that violates SR or proves it to be incorrect in some way than I can absolutely %110 guarantee that you are wrong and that you have gained that impression as a result of a misunderstanding. Trust me. I have dealt with tens and tens of similar questions from other people who thought they had refuted SR, and all of them were just confused ultimately.

Comment: The belief that the earth was plane lasted thousands of years and they were wrong.
The S.R. has only 118 years old...
And remember: There is an incompatibility between Quantum M. and Relativity at all.
So, one of these theories are not Ok.